# Why cant I search the UserAgent via looping through array for value

Tags: javascript, arrays, user-agent

Trying to detect if mobile device via searching for a few keywords in the navigator.userAgent. What am I doing wrong?

```
var usrAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

function searchArray(arr, search) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].search(search) > -1) {return true};
    }
}

searchArray(["nokia","blackberry","iphone","ipad","android","apple"], usrAgent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: indexOf

```
if (arr[i].indexOf(search) > -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition to:

```
if (search.toLowerCase().indexOf(arr[i]) >= 0) {return true};
```

Answer (score 0):

you're passing usrAgent, which is a string, to a function which is expecting search, which is a function that gets called in searchArray - you need to pass in a function reference for search that performs a search based on a search term